# Ankiconnect will not add note

Tags: anki

I am trying to use Ankconnect to add a note, the deck and the model exists and the fields are correct, but I just get "null" back (and the card is not added).

**Running this bash script**

```
echo "---------- The deck exists:"

curl localhost:8765 -X POST -d '{
    "action": "getDeckConfig",
    "version": 6,
    "params": {
        "deck": "Foo"
    }
}'


echo "---------- The model exists:"

curl localhost:8765 -X POST -d '{
  "action": "modelFieldNames",
  "version": 6,
  "params": {
    "modelName": "Auto-generated"
  }
}'

echo "---------- But adding a card fails:"

curl localhost:8765 -X POST -d '{
  "action": "addNotes",
  "version": 6,
  "params": {
    "notes": {
      "deckName": "Foo",
      "modelName": "Auto-generated",
      "fields": {
        "Question": "why?",
        "Answer": "because!",
        "Card ID": "foo"
      },
      "options": {
        "allowDuplicate": true
      },
    }
  }
}'
```

**Produces these results**

---------- The deck exists:

```
{"result": {"dyn": false, "usn": 82, "timer": 0, "replayq": true, "name": "Default", "id": 1, "lapse": {"mult": 0.0, "minInt": 1, "delays": [10], "leechAction": 0, "leechFails": 8}, "autoplay": true, "rev": {"hardFactor": 1.2, "ivlFct": 1.0, "ease4": 1.3, "perDay": 200, "fuzz": 0.05, "minSpace": 1, "bury": false, "maxIvl": 36500}, "mod": 1560476298, "maxTaken": 60, "new": {"ints": [1, 4, 7], "perDay": 20, "delays": [1, 10], "order": 1, "initialFactor": 2500, "bury": false, "separate": true, "LBGIMinBefore": 1, "LBGIMinAfter": 1, "LBEIMinBefore": 4, "LBEIMinAfter": 4}}, "error": null}
```

---------- The model exists:

```
{"result": ["Question", "Answer", "Card ID"], "error": null}
```

---------- But adding a card fails:

```
null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few errors in your JSON.

Add `"tags": []` to each of your notes objects, as it seems to be mandatory from the tests I've done but can be empty.

This will at least get you an output of `{"result": [null, null, null, null, null], "error": null}`

But then you need to fix some of your fields

- "addNotes" takes an array of "notes" objects, but you're assigning a single object to `"notes"` and not an array.
- `"modelName"` cannot be `"Auto-generated"` change it to `"Basic"`
- `"Question"` should be `"Front"`
- `"Answer"` should be `"Back"`

So this is what the object in your curl call should look like:

```
{
"action": "addNotes",
"version": 6,
"params": {
  "notes": [ 
    {
      "deckName": "Foo",
      "modelName": "Basic",
      "fields": {
        "Front": "why?",
        "Back": "because!",
        "Card ID": "foo"
      },
      "options": {
        "allowDuplicate": true
      },
      "tags": []
    } 
  ]
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The missing tags field was the problem. The other stuff (Auto-generated vs Basic etc) was residue of my real application making it into the example posted with the question, sorry about that.